# Check whether the command supports a given argument using autoconf

Tags: bash, autoconf

I am trying to use `mutool draw` in one of my projects. In my `configure.ac` file, I check for the existence of `mutool` in the system. But I also want to check whether it supports the `draw` argument. Because, until version 1.7 of `mutool`, the `draw` argument wasn't supported. Here is the line that I use to check whether `mutool` exists in the system.

```
AC_PATH_PROG(CUPS_MUDRAW, [mutool], [AC_MSG_ERROR([Required mudraw binary is missing. Please install mutool.])])
```

What should I do to check the `draw` argument? Is there any possible way for me to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you want is `AC_PATH_PROGS_FEATURE_CHECK` described under https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Generic-Programs. You have to write your `feature_check` script that tries to determine whether or not that program works for your flag.